# How to store contents of file opened by Django in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to access my file in my HTML template in Django and store this file as a string in Javascript. I've tried directly storing it via:

```
var global_data = '{{ accessed_file }}';
```

But for me that did not work. I was able to access it by loading my static files directly in the HTML document and then retrieving it with $.get.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
{% with '/path/to/file.txt' as accessed_file %}

$.get("{% static accessed_pdb %}", function(data){
 // function using data

}); 
});
{% endwith %}
```

However, I want to be able to have access to data outside of the $.get. I've tried assigning it to a global variable, but with no luck.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var global_data = '';
{% with '/path/to/file.txt' as accessed_file %}

$.get("{% static accessed_pdb %}", function(data){
 global_data = data;

}); 
 //access global_data outside of $.get
});
{% endwith %}
```

I'm using the file for a visual on my site and currently I am unable to manipulate it using HTML buttons when it is within the $.get without reloading the file again. I'm not quite sure how else to approach the problem, so any feeback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value to a hidden element

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ accessed_file }}" id="file">
```

And access it via:

```
$('#file').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the global data outside of the $.get because the result is returned to the callback function asynchronously, it will run after your code outside of $.get runs. You can use promises (https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to wait for the data.